# ibatis - How to map list of value

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I have a select statement which returns list of values of same datatype  (VARCHAR). Result is anywhere between 1 to 6 rows.I'm using `queryForList()` and storing the response in a List object. When executing I'm getting an error

> --- Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: No type handler could be found to map the property 'statusList' to the column 'null'. 
>   One or both of the types, or the combination of types is not
>   supported.

The SQL query, when executed in a SQL window, returns 3 rows. Could you please assist? Thanks in advance

```
<resultMap id="retrieveStatusResult"
    class="ie.org.model.ResponseBO">
    <result property="statusList" columnIndex="1" />
</resultMap>

<select id="retrieveStatus" parameterClass="ie.org.model.RequestBO"
    resultMap="retrieveStatusResult">
    SELECT (SELECT DESCRIPTION 
    FROM TABLEA LCD 
    WHERE LCD.CODE_DETAIL = QPL.STATUS)
    FROM  TABLEB QPL 
    WHERE QPL.QUOTE=#Quote#
    AND VERSION IN (SELECT VERSION FROM TABLEB WHERE QUOTE = #Quote#)       
</select>
```

ResponseBO.java

```
private List statusList = new ArrayList();

public List getStatusList() {
    return statusList;
}

public void setStatusList(List statusList) {
    this.statusList = statusList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mapping the results properly/your bo is wrong.

When you use `queryForList()`, you are trying to create a list of the objects you have in your resultMap. And in your BO you are trying to create a list from each row of your query answer.

You should use a BO like this:

```
private String status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

which has a proper type for the answer of your query.

To use the results of the query you call your statement like this:

```
List<ResponseBO> listStatus = new ArrayList<ResponseBO>();

listStatus = (List<ResponseBO>)queryForList("retrieveStatus",properys);
```

`propertys` is a hashmap with your query parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot axelzaro